# How do I use Mod-rewrite to clean URLs?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been playing with Mod-Rewrite to try clean up my url's but haven't had much luck with any code I've found.

My current url looks like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/id?u=1&id=wwo4955838_1917151587_n.jpg
```

But I am trying to achieve this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/id/wwo4955838_1917151587_n.jpg
```

I've not managed to achieve it so far my current code is

```
 RewriteRule  ^id$ index.php?load_page=id [NC,L,QSA]
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

HTACCESS- so far

```
# 1 ---- Establish a custom 404 File not Found page ----

ErrorDocument 404 /filenotfound.php

# 2 ---- Prevent directory file listing in all of your folders ----

IndexIgnore *


# 1 ---- Rewrites Pages And Content----

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule  ^home$ index.php?load_page=home [L]
 RewriteRule  ^meme$ index.php?load_page=meme [NC,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule  ^memesingle$ index.php?load_page=memesingle [NC,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule  ^id$ index.php?load_page=id [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is the only code you have in your htaccess file?

Comment: Hi- Ive made an edit now- I apolgise, I should have been clearer!

Comment: The other rules are working for you?

Comment: Yerp they seem to working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^id/([^/]+)/?$ /id?u=1&id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

You should enter your url like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/id/wwo4955838_1917151587_n.jpg
```

Comment: Hey I had ago adding the new Rewrite rule- but I'm just getting Not Found

The requested URL /id was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Your current url in your question is already rewrite with some rule?

Comment: Nope- I replaced "RewriteRule  ^id$ index.php?load_page=id [NC,L,QSA]" with your new code.   I will keep trying and let you know if I figure it out?

Comment: Okay so I've managed to get it to work using this - "RewriteRule  ^id/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?load_page=id [NC,L,QSA]"   But now none of my CSS or images work because it see /id/ as a directory. If you have any advice on this it would be much appreciated! ?

Comment: correct Id isn't a directory - for some reason your code dosnt work for me. The only code that has worked is- RewriteRule  ^id(/|$)([^/]+)/?$ index.php?load_page=id [NC,L,QSA] and this still has the problem of ID/ being read a directory

Comment: I've managed to get it all working now- I've added a a / on my css links which has synced everything. thankyou for your help Rahil much appreciated.